# Transfer data between hadoop clusters through VPN

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, vpn

I want to copy a file between two hadoop2.6.0 clusters `nn1` and `nn2`. Clusters can only be connected through VPN, so on namenode `nn1` I created a VPN connection to `nn2`(just namenode to namenode) and I run command on `nn1` like the following:

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://nn1:9000/user/hadoop/src hdfs://nn2:9000/user/hadoop/dest
```

Above command errors out:

```
Error: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No Route to Host from  dn1/127.0.1.1 to nn2:9000 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host;
```

where `dn1` is one of datanode in cluster `nn1`.

Is it because none of my datanodes in cluster `nn1` are VPN connected to the `nn2` cluster? I thought that I only need VPN connection between namenodes for inter cluster copying.

I'm not able to create VPN connection for each datanode in `nn1` to `nn2`, because I don't have that many VPN accounts. What would be right way to do in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how write to files in Hadoop works:

1. Client talks to Namenode about what data nodes data needs to be copied
2. Client then establishes connections to data nodes and data will be copied to data nodes directly
3. Client then updates namenode metadata about files
4. In case of distcp, client is all data nodes in the first cluster with nn1 as namenode

So, if you need VPN connection between the two hadoop clusters, then you need to have VPN connection between all nodes to all nodes. Is this production cluster? It is not typical, in enterprises VPN is required to connect to clusters from our PC. But there will be direct connectivity between the 2 clusters in the enterprises. You should not be dependent on VPN, there can be other alternatives to have direct connectivity between the clusters.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I'm in a situation where enterprise purchased private-network-only cluster from outside vendor so that there's no direct connection between a on premise cluster and a remote one. What are other alternatives then?